# NGINX *7060 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out)

Tags: nginx

I had this error today with my NGINX on Vutr, with php7:

> 2017/08/22 07:46:09 [error] 19191#19191: *7060 upstream timed out
>   (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from
>   upstream, client: 111.11.11.111, server: somedomain.com, request: "GET
>   /com$

I did a hard reset of the server and now everything is working fine. But what was it, why it happened and will it happen again?

This is my nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
        # multi_accept on;
}

http {
        ##
        # Basic Settings
        ##

        #custom added 22.08.2017
        proxy_read_timeout 300;
        #end custom
        client_max_body_size 800m;

        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        tcp_nodelay on;
        keepalive_timeout 65;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        # server_tokens off;

        # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
        # server_name_in_redirect off;

        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;

        ##
        # SSL Settings
        ##

        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

        ##
        # Logging Settings
        ##

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        ##
        # Gzip Settings
        ##

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";

        # gzip_vary on;
        # gzip_proxied any;
        # gzip_comp_level 6;
        # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
        # gzip_http_version 1.1;
        # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json 
        application/javascript text/xml application/xml appli$

        ##
        # Virtual Host Configs
        ##

        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: So this was happening consistently? Actually in such cases you should record the system parameters. Like htop, free memory, open file, etc. Now that issue is gone, it will be hard to say. Next time be prepared to gather facts when this happens

Comment: it is the first time it happened

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, i found the issue!

I had too many processes at the same time.

the problem was in php-fpm settings.

so this error I had in php logs:
(so if u have same problem check php logs)
[image]

On the web I found this [article](http://community.webcorecloud.com/tutorials/how_to_solve_php_fpm_server_reached_max_children/).

After I add change my www.conf file:

```
pm.max_children = 40
```

Then I restart the php-fpm:

```
systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service
```